# How to delete certain characters from table values?

Tags: mysql, mysql-regexp

I have a table. In one of the columns of the table , the values have this form:

`Value1(12) Value2(45) Value3(35) Value4(37) Value5(17)`

How to delete the opening parenthesis, the value inside the parentheses and the closing parenthesis? So that after updating the values would take this form:

`Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5`

**P.s:** It seems that regular expressions will help here, but how to form a query with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) in an `update`.

```
update some_table
set some_column = regexp_replace(some_column, '\\([^)]*\\)', '')
```

That says to replace anything between `()` that isn't `)`, including the `()`.

Note that `(` and `)` have special meaning in a regex so they must be escaped with a `\`. `\\` is required because `\` is also the string escape character. `'\('` becomes `'('` and the escaping is lost. `'\\('` becomes `'\('` and the escape is passed along to the regex.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/83fPFq6G).

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this code in MySql <8?

Comment: @artjob [`regexp_replace` is not in 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html). You'll have to [do it with string functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319704/looking-for-regexp-replace-alternative-on-mysql-5-7-27). There's a lot you can't do in MySQL < 8.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` which is supported on all `mysql 8.0` and above versions.

```sql
UPDATE mDemo SET value = REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '[(][0-9]{2,}[)]', '')
```

###### Explaination:

`[(][0-9]{2,}[)]`

This basically looks for a `(two digits or above)` and replaces it with an empty string, thus giving  you the desired result.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TGFA7xFJ)